# In this particular code, which would be smarter, float or integer?

Tags: java

The next code-
Float z=5/10;
I am wondering because the answer would be from the int type so it could go through (maybe?)
Would it compile?

Comment: `5/10` is integer division, always resulting in `0` no matter where you assign the result.

Comment: Did you tried it before asking?

Comment: Your answer is at [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) - *`int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `float` (primitive) and not `Float` (the wrapper type) whenever possible.

Second of all, `5/10` is a division of two `int` literals, and the result is `int` - `0`.

If that's what you want, store it in an `int` variable:

```
int z = 5/10;
```

If you want the result to be `0.5`, make sure you perform floating point division (by changing at least one of the operands from `int` to `float`) and store the result in a `float` variable:

```
float z = (float)5/10;
```

or

```
float z = 5.0f/10;
```